# New Issuer for Apple Wallet (In-App Provisioning)

Tags: ios, wallet

We are looking into the possibility to add a credit card to the Apple Wallet, currently we aren't a official issuer for Apple (see https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT206637), but we like to become one.

Unfortunately we aren't able to find where we can apply for this or where we can find the technical information. It was also hard to find it for the Google Wallet (https://developers.google.com/pay/issuers/apis/push-provisioning/android), but in the end we manage to find it.

Does anyone know how we can get the same for Apple?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To become an issuer for Apple Wallet you need to get permission from Apple to use the special entitlements by sending an email to: apple-pay-inquiries@apple.com.

More details about implementation and what you need to do here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/passkit/pkaddpaymentpassviewcontroller

Comment: FYI: when you get that permission you will need to create a new provisioning profile and you will have to signing app manually if you will have selected automatic it will not work

Comment: @LukášŠálek In your experience how long does it take to get permission or a response from Apple after you contact them at apple-pay-inquiries email address?

Comment: @most200 2-3 days